# Knocking noise over bumps

Tags: noise

Hi I don’t know anything about cars but I have this knocking/rattling noise coming from the left side of the back of my car underneath it. I have a Fiat 500 there is a metal bar hanging down abit not to sure if it’s that. The noise happens when I go over bumps mostly never on a flat straight road. Also my dad looked underneath and said a bracket was broken is this to do with the bar. I just need help to get this sorted as I’m scared when I’ve looked it up it’s saying I shouldn’t drive but I need to for work

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you edited your question and added an image of the metal bar you're talking about, it might help the question.

Comment: First check the luggage compartment to see if there is anything loose, such as a jack handle. After that, get the vehicle checked by a qualified mechanic. In my case the cause was a broken road spring, but everthing *seemed* to be all right except the knocking from a bump, but there could be other causes.

Comment: @WeatherVane does a Fiat 500 have a luggage compartment at the rear or the engine?

Comment: @SolarMike in the space behind the rear seat? The driver can't get behind the engine to hear. Besides the nit-pick, the first thing is always to check for anything loose, can you find fault with that?

Comment: @WeatherVane it’s probably the broken bracket and bar that the OP mentions.

Comment: @SolarMike that is why I next wrote: get the vehicle checked by a qualified mechanic.

Comment: You need to get the bracket replaced, as it sounds like the anti-roll bar.

Comment: @SolarMike yes it does: are you thinking of the obsolete rear-engined vehicle?

Comment: @WeatherVane Fiat 500 are still made in various versions… not sure what is obsolete…

Comment: @SolarMike which of them has a rear engine?

Comment: Stabilizer bar;  connected right and left wheels to prevent excessive movement in one wheel.  Not unusual for rubber grommets to fail and make knocking noise . It will have a bracket on each side , should not be too big a job to replace one.

Comment: I got a mechanic to come and check and He fixed it. All it was is this small protected thing that stops the springs banging on the metal but it had come loose so was just getting knocked about. Thanks everyone